# bash keeping the higest number as variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the longest_length set to the highest number.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat list_of_aways)
do
echo $i | while IFS=, read -r area name host
do
        printf "%s\n" $name
        sleep 1
        longest_length=${#name}
        printf "%s\n" "$longest_length"
        done
done
```

This is the data. The 9999999 is the longest string - I want to set that variable to the arrays value because it is the longest.

```
__DATA__
HOME,script_name_12345,USAhost.com
AWAY,script_name_123,USAhost.com
HOME,script_name_1,EUROhost.com
AWAY,script_name_123,USAhost.com
HOME,script_name_123456,EUROhost.com
AWAY,script_name_12345678999999,USAhost.com
HOME,script_name_1234,USAhost.com
AWAY,script_name_1234578,USAhost.com
HOME,script_name_12,EUROhost.com
AWAY,script_name_123456789,USAhost.com
```

Comment: Your effort is appreciable, show us a sample input and an output you need out of it, so that we can suggest better ways!

Comment: You need the string `script_name_12345678999999` as a whole or just `12345678999999` ?

Comment: You can remove everything before the pipe and put `< list_of_aways` at the end. You lose your variable because everything either side of a pipe runs in a subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it with an awk command:

```
awk -F '_|,' 'NR>1 {if ( length($4) > length(max) ) { max=$4 }} END { print max }' INPUTFILE
```

`_|,` = We are using 2 delimiters `_` and `,`

`if ( length($4) > length(max) ) { max=$4 }` = var `max` gets is compared with current 4th element in each line, and max is chosen.

`print max` = The max value is printed out.

If you want to set the result into a var called `longest_length`:

```
longest_length = `awk -F '_|,' 'NR>1 {if ( length($4) > length(max) ) { max=$4 }} END { print max }' INPUTFILE`
```